# What Wigner rotation matrix elements to use when calculating the angular dependence?

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, standard-model, group-theory, scattering

In order to work out the angular dependence of the differential cross section of an interaction, we can use the Wigner rotation matrix elements, which quantify the probability of rotating through some angle in the CM frame. I understand how this works in the case of a system in which the total spin is 1. For example in the weak interaction between a neutrino and an anti-quark:

[image]

However, I'm confused by how this is applied to a system with total spin 0. For example:

[image]

Why is it that in this case, the total spin is 0? It could also be 1, with 0 projection along the $z$ axis. In fact, as the $W$ boson is the mediator of this interaction, and it has spin 1, how is it possible to have $J = 0$ in this instance? If the total spin adds to 1 here, there would be an angular dependence going as cos(theta). There must be some physical reason to why this isn't observed, but I can't figure it out.